# How to Update specific table field's values by adding values from another table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables:

**Table1(SOURCE TABLE):
This table keeps track of all the data that is being imported.**

```
  date     | type   | volume | words | words_per | none | none_per
07-APR-21    cats    , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
07-APR-21    dogs     , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
07-APR-21    primates , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
07-APR-21    seafish  , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
06-APR-21    cats    , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
06-APR-21    dogs     , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
06-APR-21    primates , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
06-APR-21    seafish  , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
```

**Table2(TARGET TABLE): This table is the master table that sums up the values for each month**

```
  | type   | volume | words | words_per | none | none_per
   cats      , 20     , 10    ,  50%        , 10    ,50%
   dogs      , 20     , 10    ,  50%        , 10    ,50%
  primates    , 20     , 10    ,  50%        , 10    ,50%
  seafish    , 20     , 10    ,  50%        , 10    ,50%
```

This table is the target table where I want to keep updating each values by its respective type by doing an addition equation from the source table's data. For example, the volume field is (07/April + 06/April) data for each type- (10 + 10). Same for words and none. Words per/none_per are just words/volume and none/volume.

**Here is my code so far:**

```
UPDATE table2
SET volume = table1.volume + table2.volume ,
    words = table1.volume + table2.words,
  words_per =  (table2.words / table2.volume ) * 100 ,
  none =  table1.volume + table2.none ,
 none_per = (table2.none / table2.volume ) * 100
WHERE type = 'cats', 'dogs', 'primates','seafish' and 
table1.date = SELECT TO_DATE(current_date - 1) 
AS yesterday_date 
FROM dual;
```

**To things to note here.**

1. I want to only collect the latest records from table1, which would be yesterdays date
2. I have two calculation fields- "none_per" and "words_per". The logic needs to automatically update to its current logic.

I know the code above is probably pretty beginnerish but I am new to Oracle SQL so any ideas or suggestions as how to fix my code or improve it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not a smooth update, but merge as the date proceeds, seems no need to restrict to the previous day's date, but the current date. Nevertheless, no need to apply any DML statement for your case I think, a simple view with aggregation would suffice in order to replace `table2`(namely `v_table1`) such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_table1 AS
SELECT type, 
       SUM(NVL(volume,0)) AS volume, 
       SUM(NVL(words,0)) AS words, 
       AVG(NVL(words_per,0))||'%' AS words_per, 
       SUM(NVL(none,0)) AS none, 
       AVG(NVL(none_per,0))||'%' AS none_per
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY type
```